# Is possible to send HTTP code in service?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to know if it was possible to return a status from a service?
Indeed in my service I have my code which allows to register but I would like to return an error if for example an account is already existing with the mail.
I tried with `throw new HttpException()` but it does not change anything

Here is my current code:

Controller:

```
@Post('/signup')
async signup(@Body() body): Promise<void> {
    return await this.accountService.signup(body);
}
```

Service:

```
async signup(body: IAccount): Promise<void> {
    const hashedPass: string = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, await bcrypt.genSalt(10));
    const account: IAccount = {
        'uuid': uuidv4(),
        'username': body.username,
        'password': hashedPass
    };
    const newAccount = new this.accountModel(account)
    newAccount.save()
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw new HttpException('Forbidden', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    })
}
```

Thank advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever return anything from the method. You should at least return the `newAccount.save()` so that the `await` can actually wait for the response from the `catch` if there is an error

Comment: Okok I'll do an await, but how can I send an HTTP code to say that the mail is already used? Because it returns a 201 even though it's in the catch

Comment: read this https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: The reason it's sending a 201 is because there's nothing for the method to actually await. You're running the promise, and eventually throwing an error from it, but you're not making JS wait for the result of the promise before leaving the method. This is why you need to `return newAccount.save().then().catch()`. Or you need to `await newAccount.save().then().catch()`, but either way, you need to wait for the promise to finish before sending the response.